# Start multiple background jobs and print results sequentially

Tags: bash, output, background-process

I want to start a number of parallel jobs and I want the result outputs in sequential order. The jobs in my case are HTTP requests sent with `curl` and I'm interested in the response code only. Here is what I have so far:

```
for i in {1..6}
do
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
        -d 'some data' \
        -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" \
        <url of service> &
done
wait
```

This prints the result code of each request, but not in the correct order. Any way I can correct the order of the output?

It is necessary that the requests are actually sent in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Store the results to files, then print them out once everything is complete:

```
for i in {1..6}
do
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
        -d 'some data' \
        -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" \
        <url of service> > result_$i &
done
wait

for i in {1..6}
do
    cat result_$i
    rm result_$i
done
```